# Older Pokemon cards

Tags: pokemon

I can tell by checking sites that older Pokemon cards are most likely not allowed in a tournament setting.  Would that include energy and training cards?  They should seem to be generic and okay.

Answer (score 4):

The list of sets legal for tournament play in the 2015-16 season are spelled out here

http://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-news/pokemon-tcg-format-rotation-for-2016/

Basic energy is always allowed.   Special energy depends on the set in which it was released.

Pokemon allows for older cards that have been reprinted exactly and are currently legal for play.

Pokegym maintains a handy list that explains which older cards are still legal for play and why
http://pokegym.net/forums/view.php?pg=xpdformat